# Web API QueryString not passing second parameter to controller/action

Tags: c#, query-string, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API application which is expected to return a list of clinical alerts for patients. The request is invoked with the following URL

```
http://myserver:18030/api/Alerts/search?systemId=182&patientId=T000282L
```

where the systemId determines the clinical information system for which the patientID value is relevant. The routing is set up as follows in WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "Alertsapi",
           routeTemplate: "api/Alerts/search",
           defaults: new { controller = "Alerts" , action = "search"}
       );
```

and the controller actions is as follows:

```
    [ActionName("search")]
    public  List<Alert> GetAlerts(string systemId = "", string patientId = "")
    {
        var alerts = from a in db.Alerts
                    where a.alertAuthorReference.Equals(systemId)
                    where a.alertSubjectReference.Equals(patientId)
                    select a;
        return alerts.ToList();
    }
```

I was under the impression that QueryString parameters where automatically mapped to action method parameters, but in this example patientId is always null (or an empty string as I am supplying that as a default). I have tried reading the QueryString in code inside the action method, but it only has one member with key systemId.

Why isn't the second parameter being passed through?

I can work around it by using a QueryString of patientId=182:T000282L and then parsing this composite key, but I want to be able eventually to search on multiple parameters, and so may need to access a third or even fourth value from the query string.

Comment: What happens if you remove your default values from the `GetAlerts()` parameters?

Comment: If I do that the parameters are null

Comment: Both parameters, or just the `patientId`?

Comment: The second one. If I reverse the order of the parameters in the URL it is still the second one that is null.

Comment: At this point, I'd suggest trying a simple project, ensure that multiple parameters work there, and then add in your custom routes and Action attributes. Start with something like [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/pass-multiple-parameter-in-url-in-web-api/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a route for that like

```
 routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "GetPagedData",
             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{pageSize}/{pageNumber}"
        )
```

your controller will be like

```
[HttpGet]
("GetPagedResult")]
HttpResponseMessage GetPagedResult(int StartIndex, int PageSize)
{
         // you can set default values for these parameters like StartIndex = 0 etc.
}
```

Comment: That would require a URL such as `http://myserver:18030/api/Alerts/search/182/T000282L` to use my original example. I want the flexibility to search on multiple parameters. For example, I may want to search instead on name and date of birth such as `?surname=Jones&forename=Fred&dob=19450401` and I don't want to have to configure individual routes for each combination of search parameters.

Comment: why don't you use a custom object like making a class SearchFilter with 10 parameters which should be by default null and to your function just receive that object and check which parameters are given  and fill out that object from jquery and pass as data check this link http://techbrij.com/pass-parameters-aspdotnet-webapi-jquery also check this http://habrahabr.ru/post/164945/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get what you need now with Web API 2 and Attribute Routing.

Take a look at this article:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

First you'll need to edit WebApiConfig.cs

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

[...]

in your case you can test it works with this inside a controller:

```
    [Route("search")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string search(string systemId = "", string patientId = "")
    {

        return patientId;
    }
```

and to call it:

```
http://myserver:18030/search?systemId=182&patientId=T000282L
```